# Output var values declared inside a jquery $(document).ready() from Firebug Console

Tags: jquery, firebug

I have something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var numberOfTables = 3;
});
```

Is there anyway that I can access `numberOfTables` value from **Firebug** Console, without having to type inside my script something like: `console.out(numberOfTables)`?

Comment: debug your code using firebug, and you can check your variable value there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numberOfTables`  is **internal** scope.

so you cant see it

however consider **removing** the `VAR` keyword (  just for debugging !!!)

and it will `global`

so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

When the variable goes out of scope, there is nothing you can do to access it. You could set a breakpoint and examine the variable in the debugger without using `console`, but it will only be valid while in scope.

Answer (score 1):

Add debugger; inside your function (after declaring your var). Firebug will stop executing the script. Then you can just hover numberOfTables to see its value.